# How to know/log whether Hibernate 2nd-level cache was used or not for a query?

Tags: hibernate, logging, orm, grails, second-level-cache

Currently, in order to check if the Hibernate 2nd-level cache was used for a Database query, I check my SQL log (through p6spy or logSql=true in Datasource.groovy) to see if the Grais/Hibernate triggered an SQL query. And I assume that if the query was not logged, it might mean that cache was used.

It is pretty complicated for a simple information, isn't it?

So do you know a simple way to get and log the information : "Cache was used vs. DB query was triggered" ?

**EDIT**: Following Pascal recommendations, I have added this `trace 'org.hibernate.cache'` to my log4j configuration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could activate the `org.hibernate.cache` [category](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging) to log all second-level cache activity. To do so (according to the Grails [FAQ](http://www.grails.org/FAQ#Q:%20How%20can%20I%20turn%20on%20logging%20for%20hibernate%20in%20order%20to%20see%20SQL%20statements,%20input%20parameters%20and%20output%20results?)), edit your `Config.groovy` file. Find the line with:

```
hibernate = "off"
```

and replace it with:

```
hibernate.cache = "trace,stdout"
```

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is that when query logging is enabled, each query is logged.

Various statistics are available via `SessionFactory.getStatistics()` and `Session.getStatistics()`. Query execution and query cache hit and miss counts are not available on the SessionStatistics.

In a test environment, where you do not have concurrent sessions, you could perform your cacheable query twice and assert that both of `SessionStatistics.getQueryCacheHitCount()` and `SessionStatistics.getQueryExecutionCount()` only increased by 1.